# Facebook: Run a page with multiple application tabs of one application

Tags: facebook, tabs

I wanted to know if I can run a facebook with multiple application tabs all from the same application. E.g. I have a tab welcome located under /welcome of my app as well as the tab contact located under /contact. In facebook application settings I can set the domain path http://example.com/ and the page tab location as http://example.com/welcome ... but I want to use more than one tab on a page with my application <-- is this possible or should I have to create for each application tab a new application?? :-|

Greetings
Denis

Comment: Is there an official way of managing multiple tabs in your fb page other than creating apps? And without using third-party apps. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunately no. Currently you can only have one tab per app per Page. If you want to add multiple tabs to a single Page, you'll need to have a separate app for each one.

It *is* possible to serve different tab content to different Pages from one app by using the profile_id property of the [signed_request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) parameter. Check out the other properties of the signed_request parameter for more ideas about ways you can customize Page tab content on the fly.

Comment: so is there any way we can have custom tabs on page without creating apps? I just want to have tabs that load content from my website on my fb page.

Comment: Well, you might be able to [find](http://www.appbistro.com) an existing app that you can install that will just let you point it to your website but it's extremely easy to just [create an app](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) and make your website the tab URL. There's not a way to just add a tab with an arbitrary URL without involving an app in one way or another.

Comment: I know how to create an app, I just feel it's a clumsy way to manage the tabs. Oh well, fb probably doesn't want that. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Have you found a way?